# How rabbit may automatically check if consumer is still available and if not remove it from list?

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

Initial status:
Rabbit have one consumer connected to it

Event:
Network connection between rabbit and consumer broke

Result:
Consumer trying to reconnect Rabbit, but Rabbit have consumer on it's consumer list

Next Event:
Network connection is up again, consumer reconnects to Rabbit, but previous rabbit connection don't disappears.

Result:
Rabbit trying to send messages to inactive consumer

Question:
Is there any chance to rabbit automatically check if consumer is still available, and if not - removing it from the list?

Be aware that heartbeat option is on  but it does not solve a problem .

```
connectionFactory.setRequestedHeartbeat(15);
```

Used libraries are :
used libraries org.springframework.amqp:spring-rabbit:1.2.0.RELEASE
com.rabbitmq:amqp-client:3.2.1

Comment: Do you use explicit message acknowledgement?

Answer (score 1):

What versions? I just ran tests with RabbitMQ 3.3.2 and Spring-AMQP 1.3.4 and everthing works as expected.

Comment: used libraries
org.springframework.amqp:spring-rabbit:1.2.0.RELEASE
com.rabbitmq:amqp-client:3.2.1